# Mysql select winner based on two columns

Tags: mysql

How would the query look like (mysqli), if i have a number 40, and have to find the row that acually purchased ticket 40, based on start and end column?

in this case, row with id 19 would be the correct answer, because 40 is over start, and lower than 40. the player purchased ticket 2 to 1000, and won.

**How will the query be?**

Database structure:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `BETWEEN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM lotto_tickets
WHERE 40 BETWEEN start AND end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from  lotto_ticekts
where 40 between start and end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM lotto_tickets WHERE start <= 40 AND end >= 40
```